# Laravel makes array from json

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

I've made an api, now I want to use that api in my webapp. When I check the output from the api in postman the result is just json:

Result in postman:

```
"{"result":{"message":"Success","school":[{"SchoolName":"Lehner-Hackett","Company":"Dare, Bailey and Bednar","Address":"33972 Mills LockDuBuqueshire, FL 74380","Zip":"52192-","City":"Kubshirecvd","PhoneNumber":"572-489-9606435"},{"SchoolName":"O'Conner PLC","Company":"Dare, Bailey and Bednar","Address":"46849 Tara Plaza\nNew Berenicemouth, NV 36571","Zip":"24669","City":"North Francesview","PhoneNumber":"1-373-907-1357"},{"SchoolName":"Botsford-Huels","Company":"Dare, Bailey and Bednar","Address":"668 Georgiana Lights\nPort Payton, PA 90419-1623","Zip":"56373","City":"Nashville","PhoneNumber":"1-255-355-1138"}]}}"
```

In my api I return json like this:

```
return  $output = [
                    'SchoolName'    => $school->SchoolName,
                    'Company'       => $school->company->CompanyName,
                    'Address'       => $school->Address,
                    'Zip'           => $school->Zip,
                    'City'          => $school->City,
                    'PhoneNumber'   => $school->PhoneNumber
                ];
```

If I dd the result in my webapp the result is this:

```
JsonResponse {#247 ▼
  #jsonOptions: 0
  #data: "{"school":[[{"SchoolName":"Lehner-Hackett","Company":"Dare, Bailey and Bednar","Address":"33972 Mills LockDuBuqueshire, FL 74380","Zip":"52192-","City":"Kubshirecvd","PhoneNumber":"572-489-9606435"},{"SchoolName":"O'Conner PLC","Company":"Dare, Bailey and Bednar","Address":"46849 Tara Plaza\nNew Berenicemouth, NV 36571","Zip":"24669","City":"North Francesview","PhoneNumber":"1-373-907-1357"},{"SchoolName":"Botsford-Huels","Company":"Dare, Bailey and Bednar","Address":"668 Georgiana Lights\nPort Payton, PA 90419-1623","Zip":"56373","City":"Nashville","PhoneNumber":"1-255-355-1138"}]]}"
  #callback: null
  #encodingOptions: 15
  +headers: ResponseHeaderBag {#245 ▶}
  #content: "{"school":[[{"SchoolName":"Lehner-Hackett","Company":"Dare, Bailey and Bednar","Address":"33972 Mills LockDuBuqueshire, FL 74380","Zip":"52192-","City":"Kubshirecvd","PhoneNumber":"572-489-9606435"},{"SchoolName":"O'Conner PLC","Company":"Dare, Bailey and Bednar","Address":"46849 Tara Plaza\nNew Berenicemouth, NV 36571","Zip":"24669","City":"North Francesview","PhoneNumber":"1-373-907-1357"},{"SchoolName":"Botsford-Huels","Company":"Dare, Bailey and Bednar","Address":"668 Georgiana Lights\nPort Payton, PA 90419-1623","Zip":"56373","City":"Nashville","PhoneNumber":"1-255-355-1138"}]]}"
  #version: "1.0"
  #statusCode: 200
  #statusText: "OK"
  #charset: null
}
```

Why do I receive something else then in my webapp?

Comment: I don't understand what is not working and what you are trying to get, please clarify further in the question.

Comment: @fire I've changed it hope it's better to understand now